# Share Data between different Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to share a String value between 4 different fragments.
If I change in one Fragment a value, I want to send this value to the other fragments.

How should I do that?

The only thing I know is that in one fragment I can change a TextView like

```
String newValue = "New Text";
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
Textview tv = (Textview) v.findViewById(R.id.textview_from_fragment_one);
tv.setText(newValue);
```

But how can I send newValue e.G. to the fragments fragment_two and fragment_three?

Comment: for starters, i would recommend you look into eventbus - https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus
you can look up examples/tutorials on how to integrate it

Comment: use interface https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: have you done any search before asking the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library, [here](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/) is the tutorial of how to get started with EventBus.

Also you can achieve this with RxJava with [this](https://lorentzos.com/rxjava-as-event-bus-the-right-way-10a36bdd49ba) tutorial.

But if you don't want to use any library then :

1. First  of all create an Interface like below :

   ```
   public interface Data {

       void dataChanged(String changedString);

   }
   ```
2. Implement this interface in all of your fragments like this :

   ```
   public class FirstFragment extends Fragment implements Data {

       ...

       @Override
       public void dataChanged(String changedString){

           // In this method you'll receive the changed string value

       }

   }
   ```
3. Create a method inside your activity like below :

   ```
   public void changeData(String changedData){

       // Notify your first fragment
       Data data = myFirstFragment;
       data.dataChanged(changedData);

       // Notify your second fragment
       data = mySecondFragment;
       data.dataChanged(changedData);

       // Other fragments
       ...

   }
   ```
4. whenever you changed that string value, notify other fragments like this :

   ```
   // Call this inside your fragment
   ((YourActivity)getActivity()).changeData(CHANGED_VALUE);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html):

```
String newValue = "New Text";

Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
// you can put as much fragments as you want

NewFragment fragment = new NewFragment(); 
SecondFragment fragment_two = new SecondFragment(); 
ThirdFragment fragment_three = new ThirdFragment(); 

bundle.putString("some_tag", newValue ); 
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
fragment_two.setArguments(bundle);
fragment_three.setArguments(bundle);
```

In any of the fragments you set to have this value add this:

```
if (bundle != null) 
{
    String newValue = getArguments().getString("some_tag");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bundle such as (put extra in start activity) for fragments:

1. When call Fragment in activity:

   ```
   Fragment fragment = new ExampleFragment(); 

   FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString("key", "TEST");
   fragment.setArguments(bundle);

   transaction.replace(R.id.frame , fragment);
   transaction.commit();
   ```
2. In Fragment Put this in onViewCreated():

   ```
    String exampleString;
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
       if (bundle != null) {
        exampleString = bundle.getString("key", "");

       Toast.makeText(getActivity() , exampleString , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   ```

NOTE: Use Interface for call methode in activity for replace fragment.